# counting the number of child contours inside a contour in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, contour

I have this source image

[image]

and I have applied binary thresholding to get this

[image]

I used contours to differentiate between the ones having child contours and ones that don't.The resultant pic is

[image]

But how do I count the number of child contours that each green contour contains?. This is code I have used:-

```
Mat binMask = lung;// the thresholded image
Mat lung_src = imread("source.tiff");// the source image
//imshow("bin mask", binMask);
vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
int count = 0, j;

double largest_area = 0;
int largest_contour_index = 0;

findContours(binMask, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0));

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    double a = contourArea(contours[i], false);  //  Find the area of contour
    if (a>largest_area)
    {
        largest_area = a;
        largest_contour_index = i;
    }
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if (hierarchy[j][2] != -1) // means it has child contour
        {

                drawContours(lung_src, contours, j, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());

        }           
        else  // means it doesn't have any child contour
        {
            drawContours(lung_src, contours, j, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
        }
    }
}
drawContours(lung_src, contours, largest_contour_index, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
imshow("lung-mapped", lung_src);
```

EDIT-1- I added the code from Humam at the end to check it out:

```
std::vector<int> number_of_inner_contours(contours.size(), -1);
int number_of_childs = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{

    int first_child_index = hierarchy[i][2];
    if (first_child_index >= 0)
    {
        int next_child_index = hierarchy[first_child_index][0];
        if (number_of_inner_contours[next_child_index]<0)
        {
            number_of_childs = number_of_inner_contours[next_child_index];
        }
        else
        {
            while (next_child_index >= 0)
            {
                next_child_index = hierarchy[next_child_index][0];
                ++number_of_childs;
            }
            number_of_inner_contours[i] = number_of_childs;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        number_of_inner_contours[i] = 0;
    }
    cout << "\nThe contour[" << i << "] has " << number_of_inner_contours[i] << "child contours";
}
```

But the output I got was like :

```
      The contour[456 ] has 0 child contours
      The contour[457 ] has 0 child contours
      The contour[458 ] has 0 child contours
      The contour[459 ] has -1 child contours
```

Answer (score 1):

From [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) :

> **hierarchy** – Optional output vector, containing information about the
>   image topology. It has as many elements as the number of contours. For
>   each i-th contour contours[i] , the elements hierarchy[i][0] ,
>   hiearchy[i](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) , hiearchy[i][2] , and hiearchy[i][3] are set to
>   0-based indices in contours of the next and previous contours at the
>   same hierarchical level, the first child contour and the parent
>   contour, respectively. If for the contour i there are no next,
>   previous, parent, or nested contours, the corresponding elements of
>   hierarchy[i] will be negative.

This is untested code for doing the job:

```
std::vector<size_t> number_of_inner_contours;
number_of_inner_contours.reserve(contours.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
    size_t number_of_childs = 0;   
    auto first_child_index=hierarchy[i][2];
    if(first_child_index>=0){
        auto next_child_index=hierarchy[first_child_index][0];
        while (next_child_index>=0){
            next_child_index=hierarchy[next_child_index][0];
            ++number_of_childs;
        }
        number_of_inner_contours.emplace_back(number_of_childs);
    }
    else{
         number_of_inner_contours.emplace_back(0);
    }
}
```

This code could be done in a better way by using the concept of dynamic programming. This is a first try also:

```
std::vector<int> number_of_inner_contours(contours.size(),-1);
for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
    auto number_of_childs = 0;   
    auto first_child_index=hierarchy[i][2];
    if(first_child_index>=0){
        auto next_child_index=hierarchy[first_child_index][0];
        if(number_of_inner_contours[next_child_index]<0){
            number_of_childs=number_of_inner_contours[next_child_index];
        }
        else{
            while (next_child_index>=0){
                next_child_index=hierarchy[next_child_index][0];
                ++number_of_childs;
            }
            number_of_inner_contours[i]=number_of_childs;
        }
    }
    else{
         number_of_inner_contours[i]=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry,but your code doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: Could you give some clarification for " doesn't give the desired result". I edited an error that was in the code. You may try it again

Comment: @Humam-can u check this out?